# Using a slide transition (AP1 level 21) with up button?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions, up-button

I am trying to set a transition for returning to the parent activity when the up button is pressed in one of my activities. I want to use the slide transition introduced in API level 21, but that doesn't work with overridePendingTransition which is how I would do this with an animation defined in xml.

I set the enter and exit transitions for both activities but those don't seem to activate when the up button is pressed.

Is there another way to use this transition effect? Maybe a way to define an animation in xml to mimic the effect?

The code in question:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        //How to use slide transition here?
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks